# Momentum question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, momentum

The problem:

> In a car crash, a passenger with a mass of 82kg is not wearing a
>   seatbelt. The car is travelling at 45km per hour. What impulse must
>   the car's airbag provide in order to stop the passenger's motion?
>
> Explain why hitting an airbag will cause less injury than if a
>   passenger hits the dashboard.

Here is what I did:

I thought impulse meaning force, so to find force I can use $F = m\Delta v/\Delta t$. But I don't know what $t$ is. How can I find $t$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Impulse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_%28physics%29) is the product of the force and the time over which it is applied, and tells you the total change in momentum:
$$I = F\Delta t = \Delta p$$.